# Is it bad practice to disable OS-based 'Features'?

Tags: shell, user-interface, operating-system

One thing that I can't get my head around is the persistent questioning here, and elsewhere on the web, about disabling OS-based 'features'.  People are forever asking how to disable default OS shortcuts (like copy-paste, the Windows key, etc.), or disabling features programmatically.

Surely this is very, very bad practice?  To modify a user's operating environment with your program, unless it's specifically targeted at helping the used to modify their own operating environment (which, in the majority of cases I've seen, I highly doubt it).  I'd never want a program modifying my bound shortcuts, or changing the default behaviour/feature-set of my environment.  Is that a general consensus, or is that just me?  It violates virtually every base heuristic and usability/consistency theory I can think of - not least of which, the principle of least astonishment.

**The question, then, is this:** *Is there ever a time (aside from when aiding the user in modifying their environment) when manipulating/changing/disabling features of the operating system, or of the user's general environment, is acceptable practice?*  Should a program ever attempt to disable the Windows key, copy/paste shortcuts, adjust the Start button text, or anything of a similar vein, without the user's explicit permission, and without the change being fundamentally necessary to the execution of the purpose of the program?

Comment: See also [SE UX: _Is it bad practice to disable (replace) the_ \[browser's\] _context menu?_](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/145819/67216) [in a webapp].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Meta answer:** It may be a good idea if-and-only-if your *real* reason for doing it so is in the user's interest.

And don't try to lie to the user about doing it for "security". You can count on being publicly named and shamed.

If you are limiting the user for *your* advantage, and not theirs, you are in dangerous territory, indeed. Crippling my machine without my express permission will get you put forever on the filter-with-extreme-prejudice list...

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is perfectly acceptable if you are building an "appliance" for example like the kiosks you find in bookstores. In cases like these it does make sense to disable most of the known shortcuts and features.

Comment: I believe this, as well as overslacked's answer, both fall into the category of "fundamentally necessary to the purpose of the program". To further generalize, i would say that such modification is appropriate for any situation where the OS is being used as part of a larger "application", rather than as a tool for application-independent control over the computer.

Answer (score 4):

No.

For normal applications, where the user expects to be in control and may well be running other apps, this sort of behavior serves only to subvert the user's expectations, may damage native accessibility features of the OS, and will generally lead to frustration.

Even exceptions such as those noted by [ocdecio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873507/disabling-os-based-features-bad-practice/873533#873533) and [overslacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873507/disabling-os-based-features-bad-practice/873530#873530), though well-intentioned, may fall into this trap (how many games have you played that would crash leaving important system features disabled, or kiosks that disabled task switching but forgot to disable system notifications...) Whenever possible, developers should look first to the OS itself for support in implementing full-screen, restricted, or kiosk applications.

BTW - marking CW, very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so, although it's rare and should be very temporary. For example, a DVD player disabling the screen saver, or a presentation, game, or "parent-ware" type app disabling the Windows key.

It's very good advice to avoid doing these things, but there are times when it's appropriate and even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen apps (including the Windows OS, I think) that disable cut and paste when in a password text box.

I would agree that there are rare reasons, but that is is bad practice in general.

Comment: I hate those apps. It's my password, my clipboard, and my time wasted typing in a long, cryptic password specifically designed to be difficult to remember and type...

Comment: @Shog9 The apps that I know re this do that just for C&Ping _out_ of the pwd text box, not C&Ping _into_ it. I think that's what Doug meant. (OK, perhaps it was different in 2009. I'm really not able to remember. :)

Answer (score 1):

An example of a good divergence from normal interface behaviour is Ctrl-C on a terminal emulator on winblows.

In general, disabling "the normal" O/S interface features is obviously silly. Can you imagine having to search for the brake pedal in a hire car? How safe would feel about driving it off the lot? Having to search for the lights, wipers, indicators, and hand brake is bad enough... The brake pedal should be the one the middle, or the left;-) It Works. Don't Effin Eff With It!

Having said that: [Neil Frasers blog](http://neil.fraser.name/news/2005/01/22/) systematically destructs many of the "universal tenets" of UI design by evaluating their application to the venerable TI80 programmable caclulator. The phrase "This results in an inferior calculator" somehow branded itself into my brain.

I believe *consistency* of interface is paramount. For instance, I use a product called SOATest. It's an Eclipse based Java app for testing SOAP (et al.) web-services. It has one **very** annoying quirk. Ctrl-Insert and Shift-Insert don't work in any of its text areas, but they do work in many (not all) of its text-boxes. If those keys consistently didn't work I would adapt far more readily. I find this little quirk terribly annoying because (to me as a professional programmer) it represents "just plain ole **sloppy** work".

So... Keiths first rule of UI design: Whatever you do, FFS do it consistently! Your users are smart, they will adapt.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Please call Windows what it is. I am even one of those obnoxious open source/Linux people and I call it Windows. Even M$ gets on my nerves sometimes (although that name is more rightly deserved; I would love to see Microsoft die).

Comment: Wait... you complain that he refers to Windows by an unofficial name, and in the VERY SAME COMMENT you refer to Microsoft as M$? (I don't have a problem with either reference, it just seemed awfully hypocritical.